# Image Merging using Quad Tree

Tags: image, algorithm, tree

How can we merge two images using quad-trees ? I was browsing wikipedia for [Quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) and saw images can be represented using a quad-tree . The algorithm for this was once asked in a Google Interview as well.

Comment: 2 images are given , say you have their pixels ,one image has letter A and other has B , then the merged image will have letters AB. This is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

Well I just read about the Quadtree's and by my understanding the Quadtree is a tree which each of his roots has exactly 4 children.
It is also noted that it is a good structure to represent images in a way that the root is the whole image, his 4 children divide the image into 4 equal pieces and so on.
This can be seen nicely in this image:[image]

Now the way I see it, the whole image has to form a square, because having 4 equal squares always forms a square, in order to have a rectangle from a Quadtree it must have "empty" fillings of the remnants of the square, as can be seen from the "white" squares in the image above.

So lets say we are given 2 rectangles, and we want to append them together horizontally, 
The most straightforward way to my understanding is just creating a new tree, with a new root, and adding the 1st Image as the 1st child of that root, the 2nd Image as the 2nd child of that root, and the 3rd and 4th children will have "empty" fillings.
That way if the Images append to each other nicely, you will have a good image outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the tree is represented like this,

```
class Node {
  Color color;
  List<Node> children;
}
```

Would something like this work ?

```
Node mergeNode(Node first, Node second) {
  if ( first == null || second == null )
  {
    return first == null ? second : first;
  }
  else
  {
    List<Node> newKids = new ArrayList<Node>();
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; ++i )
    {
        Node merged = mergeNode(first,second);
        newKids.set(i,merged);
    }
    return new Node(mergeColors(first,second),newKids));
  }
}
```

Where `mergeColors` is your strategy to resolve the colors merging (something similar to a truth table).